# Sort an array using ratio

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to sort an array by the win and lose ratio of the players.

My code looks like this actually:

```js
const array = [{playerName: 'toto', win: 2, lose: 2}, {playerName: 'titi', win: 0, lose: 0}, {playerName: 'tata', win: 3, lose: 1}];
    array.sort((a, b) => a.win / a.lose || b.win / b.lose);
    console.log(array);
```

The player 'titi' is above the player 'toto' inside the sorted array and I don't know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of issues with your sort function. Firstly, you are dividing by `a.lose` and `b.lose` which for your sample data are both `0` so those division will return `Infinity`. Secondly, a [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) callback should return a negative number, `0`, or a positive number dependent on whether `a` should be sorted lower than, equal to or greater than `b` respectively and yours - due to your logic - will always return a positive number. I think what you actually want is:

```js
const array = [{
  playerName: 'toto',
  win: 2,
  lose: 2
}, {
  playerName: 'titi',
  win: 0,
  lose: 0
}, {
  playerName: 'tata',
  win: 3,
  lose: 1
}];
array.sort((a, b) => {
  if (a.win + a.lose == 0) return 1;
  if (b.win + b.lose == 0) return -1;
  return b.win / (b.win + b.lose) - a.win / (a.win + a.lose);
});
console.log(array);
```

Comment: I modified my post to get a trickiest situation, i want tata first, toto second, and titi last

Comment: @SMAKSS I've updated the answer to deal properly with players who have no results (win = lose = 0)

Comment: @asa I've updated the answer to deal properly with players who have no results (win = lose = 0)

Answer (score 0):

[look here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

to be more specific:
If compareFunction(a, b) returns greater than 0, sort b to an index lower than a (i.e. b comes first).

in your case its 1/0 which values to `Infinity` which is true value thus it never calculates the b part. when you return `true` it's the same as returning 1.

Answer (score 0):

I found your problem solution for sorting array.
this way you easy to understend.
this code answer is descending order of win or lose index parameter.
Some small change of your code is following:

```js
const array = [
  {playerName: 'toto', win: 1, lose: 0}, 
  {playerName: 'titi', win: 0, lose: 0}
];
    
array.sort((a, b) => { 
   if(a.win > b.win ||  a.lose < b.lose) { 
      return 1; 
   } 
   return -1;
});
console.log(array);
```

if you have to change order then replace "<" with ">" and ">" with "<".

Answer (score 0):

Take cases where sum of wins and loses is zero wiht comparing function

```
const sortPlayers =(a, b) => {
  if (a.win + a.lose + b.win + b.lose === 0) {
    return 0
  } else if (a.win + a.lose === 0 && b.win + b.lose !== 0) {
    return 1
  } else if (a.win + a.lose !== 0 && b.win + b.lose === 0) {
    return -1
  } else if ((a.win/(a.win + a.lose) > (b.win/(b.lose + b.win)))) {
    return -1
  } else if ((a.win/(a.win + a.lose) < (b.win/(b.lose + b.win)))) {
    return 1
  } else {
    return 0
  }
}
const array = [{playerName: 'toto', win: 1, lose: 0}, {playerName: 'titi', win: 0, lose: 0}];
array.sort((a, b) => sortPlayers(a, b));



console.log(array)
```

Comment: Same result, the player titi is second on the new situation

Comment: Atleast with playcode.io order with this is tata - toto -titi

Answer (score -1):

The sort function must return an integer that defines the order of the items.

You're returning the result of the OR (||) operation instead.

Please check:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort